# What would be the best way for the get route for this business MongoDB Schema to return only the tags that are true?

Tags: mongodb, express, mern

I am currently working on a webapp that displays information about local businesses during quarantine and am currently working on the get/post/put routes. I am using Mongoose in order to construct the data and express to construct the routes.

This is our current get route in the file business.js

```
router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
      Business.find()
         .then(business => res.json(business))
         .catch(error => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + error));
});
```

This is our business schema in the file business.model.js

```
 const businessSchema = new Schema({
      businessName: { type: String, required: true },
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      phoneNum: { type: Number, required: true },
      websiteURL: { type: String, required: true },
      description: { type: String, required: true },
      type: { type: String , required: true },

      //tags
      curbside: {type: Boolean, default: false},
      delivery: {type: Boolean, default: false},
      subscription: {type: Boolean, default: false},
      black_owned: {type: Boolean, default: false},
      organic: {type: Boolean, default: false},
      event: {type: Boolean, default: false},
      female_owned: {type: Boolean, default: false},


      price: {type: Number, required: false},
      rating: {type: Number, required: false},
      hours: {type: Map, required: true},
      images: {type: Array, required: false},
      products: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}],
      users: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
      }, {
        timestamps: true,
});
```

So the issue I am currently having is getting the JSON that the get route returns to show only the tags that are true for each business.

Answer (score 0):

simply modify your query like

```
  Business.find({ // it will match all tags keys to true
      curbside: true,
      delivery: true,
      subscription: true,
      black_owned: true,
      organic: true,
      event: true,
      female_owned: true,
})
```